# Flutter Fill in Blank with RichText

Tags: flutter, abstract-class, richtext

I am almost done with fill in blanks implementation for my app but unfortunately I keep running into layout issues.

However as I keep solving the issues I am almost done with it, this is the code so far:

```dart
                        RichText(
                            text: TextSpan(
                                text: "dummy",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    height: 1.5,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                children: <InlineSpan>[
                                  TextSpan(
                                      text:
                                          ' to  to  to  to gdfgdfgdf to  to  to  to  to  to  to  ',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          height: 1.0,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  WidgetSpan(
                                    alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
                                    child: SecretWord("turtle"),
                                  ),
                                  TextSpan(
                                      text:
                                          ' to  to  to  to gdfgdfgdf to  to  to  to  to  to  to  ',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          height: 1.0,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            )
```

And my SecretWord class:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

class SecretWord extends StatelessWidget {

    final String answer;
    int answerLength;
    String answerHint;
    double answerWidth;

    SecretWord(this.answer){
        this.answerLength = answer.length;
        this.answerHint = '.' * answerLength;
        this.answerWidth = this.answerLength * 15.0;
    }

    String value = "";

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            //alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            width: answerWidth,
            height: null,

          //  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
            child: TextFormField(
                maxLines: null,
                cursorColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
                cursorRadius: Radius.circular(12.0),
                cursorWidth: 2.0,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: (value == answer) ? Colors.amberAccent : Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    letterSpacing: 3,
                  //  height: 0.5,
                ),
                //textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                autofocus: false,
                maxLength: answerLength,
                onChanged: (text) {
                    value = text;

                },

                decoration: new InputDecoration(

                    //labelText: 'Name *',
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                    counterText: '',
                    hintText: answerHint,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(

                        color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        letterSpacing: 4,
                       // height: 0.5,
                    ),
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this create some issues: the container height of SecretWord is superior to TextSpan, how could I succeed to reduce the height of the Container with TextFormField to match the height of TextSpan ?

[image]

Notice that the second line has more space with first and third line than what I was expecting, it is because SecretWord is considered to take more space vertically. I know the cause but not how to solve it.

Comment: Try use `Expanded`widget

Comment: I tried but it is even worse, I get line return for each SecretWord(). Do you have a working example ?

Comment: Can you share picture of the layout issue you are seeing ?

Comment: I just added the picture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello I've come up with a solution to reduce the inner padding of TextField/TextFormField which looks like your problem.

Setting these values for the InputDecoration of the TextField should remove the vertical padding:

```
     TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: -5),
          counterText: '',
        ),
      )
```

> **isDense=true** makes the input is part of dense form (i.e., uses less vertical
>     /// space).
>
> setting **contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: -5)** will reduce the vertical padding
>
> As you already did in your example **counterText: ''** will prevent the counter text being shown.

So here is your new SecretWordClass with the changes. I also moved the properties under the build method since stateless widgets are immutable and their properties should be final.

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

class SecretWord extends StatelessWidget {
  final String answer;

  SecretWord(this.answer);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String value = "";
    int answerLength = answer.length;
    String answerHint = '.' * answerLength;
    double answerWidth = answerLength * 15.0;
    return Container(
      width: answerWidth,
      height: null,
      child: TextFormField(
        maxLines: null,
        cursorColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
        cursorRadius: Radius.circular(12.0),
        cursorWidth: 2.0,
        style: TextStyle(
          color:
              (value == answer) ? Colors.amberAccent : Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 20,
          letterSpacing: 3,
        ),
        autofocus: false,
        maxLength: answerLength,
        onChanged: (text) {
          value = text;
        },
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: -5),
          counterText: '',
          border: InputBorder.none,
          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: answerHint,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            letterSpacing: 4,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here are the results:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Ali, exactly what I was looking for, also thank you for the extra tip about moving properties under the build method!

Comment: Your welcome. I'm glad that this kinda hacky way has worked for you. Good luck with your app.