# Flutter : How to use { } to have different kind of widgets in for loops

Tags: for-loop, flutter, flutter-layout

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441168/iterating-through-a-list-to-render-multiple-widgets-in-flutter), how do you iterate with a for loop to render different widgets ?

I give you an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```dart
final List<String> mylist = ["baba", "bibi", "bobo"];
final List<String> mylist2 = ["haha", "hihi", "hoho"];

...


                             children: <InlineSpan>[

                                    for ( int i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++ )
                                    { // this does not work unfortunately
                                            TextSpan(
                                                text: mylist[i],
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    height: 1.0,
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 20,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                ),
                                            MySpan(
                                                text: mylist2[i],
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    height: 1.0,
                                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                                    fontSize: 20,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                ),


                                       }  // this does not work 



                                ]
```

of course I can make the following work:

```dart
                                    for ( int i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++ )

                                            TextSpan(
                                                text: mylist[i],
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    height: 1.0,
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 20,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                ),
```

But I want the other widget to follow.

So how to wrap many items in the for loop to render different kind of items ? It is easily done with React, but for Flutter I have yet to figure out how this could be working.

Comment: Can't you have a single list of a map?

Comment: No. That is why I ask the question... I use very different kind of Widgets. I just simplified for the question.

Comment: You can create one function which takes two lists arguments and return a list of widget that can be assigned `children:`.

Comment: I know but 'List<InlineSpan>' is not a subtype of type 'InlineSpan'

Comment: Do it like this `children: createTheList(mylist1, mylist2)`

Comment: I just solved it, if you have a more elegant way give a full detailed answer and I will gladly select if it works

Comment: check @shubham's answer, he wrote exactly what I just told you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try making a `List<InlineSpan>` and use it in `RichText` directly
Here is an example.

```
List<InlineSpan> getData(List mylist,List mylist2) {
  List<InlineSpan> temp = [];

  for (int i = 0; i < mylist.length; i++) {
    temp.add(
      TextSpan(
      text: mylist[i],
      style: TextStyle(
        height: 1.0,
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  );

   temp.add(
     TextSpan(
       text: mylist2[i],
       style: TextStyle(
         height: 1.0,
         color: Colors.blue,
         fontSize: 20,
         fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
       ),
     ),
   );
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Then use it like

```
RichText(
  text:TextSpan(
    children:getData(mylist,mylist2),
    )
 );
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try, looks more readable than what I came up.

Comment: You can try it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/bc6a7ef7469f9611eb8d69c8b1a02522)

Comment: unfortunately it does not work: type 'MySpan"' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61902559/flutter-fill-in-blank-with-richtext , MySpan is the class SecretWord

Comment: Since your `MySpan` is a `Widget` replace `TextSpan` with `WidgetSpan`.

Comment: I checked again, it is in fact rightfully working, thank you for the clean answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it using a ternary, very ugly but hey, it works:

```dart
children: <InlineSpan>[

                                    for ( int i = 0; i < mylist.length * 2; i++ )
                                            i & 1 == 0 ? TextSpan(
                                                text: mylist[(i / 2).toInt()],
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    height: 1.0,
                                                    color: Colors.white,
                                                    fontSize: 20,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                ) :
                                            MySpan(
                                                text: mylist2[(i / 2).toInt()],
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    height: 1.0,
                                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                                    fontSize: 20,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                ),
                                ]
```